# jquery works on second click only (but works fine in localhost...)

Tags: javascript, jquery

The title says it all pretty much. The page loads another one and then refresh. (the 'name' attribute contains the 'id' of the element to like)

```
$('#body')
.on('click', '.dislike' , function() {
    $.get('dislike.php'+this.name);
    location.reload();
    return false;
});
```

The browser doesn't change anything (chrome, firefox, safari, safari for iPad). When I'm in localhost (or on the network using 192.168.xzy) it works perfectly. However, when I publish my code on an external server, it takes 2 times to work... (on any browser)

The reason the code is inside the `$('#body')` element is because I load more stuff dynamically.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: no errors in the console

Comment: you mentioned ipad. try using touchstart event for touchscreen devices

Comment: it's making things worse... now it works 5% of time (on the iPad)

Comment: use both click and touchstart like .bind("click touchstart", function(){

})

Comment: I did `$(document).bind('click', function(event) {
    $(event.target).trigger('touchstart');
});`

Comment: this wont work because on ipad it won't even fire this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#body').on('click touchstart', '.dislike' , function() {
        $.get('dislike.php'+this.name);
        location.reload();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this wrapped inside a

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  your_code;
});
```

That would be my first attempt if something seems to be wrong in the databinding, as other servers may run differently have issues that your localhost wouldn't.

Comment: It seems to work on Firefox. However, on my iPad it works completely randomly.... it worked like 50% of the times I tried...

Answer (score 0):

Is body an id of body tag?? if yes then you are going good. If not, then remove the # from it.

```
$('#body')
    .on('click touchstart', '.dislike' , function() {
        $.get('dislike.php'+this.name);
        location.reload();
        return false;
    });
```

see if this helps you.

Comment: it works! but if I add another one with '.like' then it kinda works.... 50% of time lol... whatever